# What tag should be used for Ruby's hashes?

Tags: discussion, tags

What tag should be used to describe hash objects in Ruby and Ruby-on-Rails? Currently, it is [hash](/questions/tagged/hash). Should it be:

1. [hash](/questions/tagged/hash): 2,597 questions overall, by far the most common term in Ruby, being used 392 times. However, I suspect it's the wrong tag, as it's described as "... mathematical function that converts a large, possibly variable-sized amount of data into a small datum".
2. [dictionary](/questions/tagged/dictionary): 2,559 questions overall, 10 uses with Ruby. Described as "... a collection of keys and values allowing efficient value lookup given the key."
3. [hashmap](/questions/tagged/hashmap): 770 questions overall, 7 uses with Ruby. No wiki yet.
4. [hashtable](/questions/tagged/hashtable): 704 questions overall, 9 uses with Ruby. Described as "... a collection that uses a hash function to map identifying values (keys) to their associated values."
5. [hashes](/questions/tagged/hashes): 52 questions overall, 11 uses with Ruby. No wiki yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ruby hash object is a hashmap/hashtable which are both types of dictionaries. I would tag it with either [hashmap](/questions/tagged/hashmap) or [hashtable](/questions/tagged/hashtable). I'm leaning towards [hashtable](/questions/tagged/hashtable) though.

I'd also create a tag synonym for hashmap and hashtable, but I don't have a score of 5 in those tags.

Comment: Glad we agree on making them synonyms.  Any reason you'd prefer `hashtable`, though?

Comment: @Matthew, I'm really kind of torn, it's a slight lean haha. I think (but I'm not sure) that more languages have a built in structure called HashTable than HashMap though.

Comment: HashMap would be slightly confusing because they might think you're calling `map` on a hash object, so I'd prefer hashtable.

Answer (score 3):

`hash` and `hashes` should be synonyms, and the tag should make clearer that it applies to hash values as well as hash functions.

Ruby hash objects are hash maps, from what I can tell of reading [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html), since they allow nulls (nils).  It depends on your definition of the terms, though, and it varies between languages/packages; either way there's really not much difference from a hash table, so it might actually make sense to merge `hashtable` and `hashmap`.

You might want something like `ruby-hash` to map to `hashmap` as well, to help avoid people inappropriately tagging questions with `hash`.

Comment: Is it possible to create a tag deliberately as a synonym?

Comment: @Andrew Mods can do it via merging.

Comment: This still needs to be done. I just  tagged a Ruby-Hash question `hash` as well as `dictionary`. No one will know to tag `ruby-hash` or `hash-table` unless it's a suggestion when typing `hash` or `dictionary`.